# how to create a shortcuts to .jar files linux

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint

having a little trouble making a short cut for a jar folder could someone explain why what I've is wrong and what to do.

[image]

Comment: `Command` is unlikely to accept a raw shell script. Try `java -jar /full/path/to/file.jar` or `bash -c 'cd /full/path; java -jar file.jar` instead.

Comment: yeah that worked cheers java -jar /full/path/to/file.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Command` entry of a shortcut is unlikely to accept a raw shell script like that.

Try `java -jar /full/path/to/file.jar` or `bash -c 'cd /full/path; java -jar file.jar` instead.